# Are files from /tmp automatically deleted by AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, tmp

Does AWS clear the `/tmp` directory automatically?

Is there a `flush()` sort of function? If not, how can I remove/delete all the files from the `/tmp` folder?

I have an AWS Lambda function where I download a file to my `/tmp` folder. I unzip the zipped file and gzip all individual files. All this happens within the `/tmp` directory and before I upload the gzipped files to S3 again.

Afterwards, I no longer need the files in my `/tmp` folder & would like to clear the directory.

If I open `/tmp` from my local macOS machine, I don't see any related files at all so I am not sure how to check if they are successfully deleted or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, files from `/tmp` are not automatically deleted.**

---

The [AWS Lambda FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/#AWS_Lambda_functions) state:

> To improve performance, AWS Lambda may choose to **retain an instance of your function and reuse it** to serve a subsequent request, rather than creating a new copy. To learn more about how Lambda reuses function instances, visit our documentation. **Your code should not assume that this will always happen.**

As per the above doc and experience, you may find an empty or "pre-used" `/tmp` directory depending on if AWS Lambda has reused a previous Lambda environment for your current request.

This may, or may not be suitable depending on the use case & there's no guarantees so **if you need to ensure a clean `/tmp` directory on every function invocation, clear the `/tmp` directory yourself**.

---

> Is there a flush() sort of function?

No, AWS does not (& shouldn't) offer a way programmatically via their SDK as this is related to file I/O.

How to delete all files inside the `/tmp` directory will be dependent on the Lambda function runtime.

For Python, try:

```
from subprocess import call
...
call('rm -rf /tmp/*', shell=True)
```

Comment: how can I specify a file name here? a particular file to be deleted from tmp. Variable form

Comment: `call('rm -rf /tmp/' + 'myspecialfile.txt', shell=True)` - replace `myspecialfile.txt` with your variable

Comment: I meant variable outside the call function...so I can run it in a loop

Comment: Specify the variable outside then use inside - it's just like any other Python code :) then call `call` as many times as you like

Comment: I tried this ```filename = 'test'
call(f"rm -rf /tmp/{filename}", shell=True)```but throws an invalid syntax error

Comment: Try `filename = 'test' call("rm -rf /tmp/" + filename, shell=True)`